# Validar que un emai introducido en un registro ya existe en la base de datos php

Tags: php, mvc, registro

tengo este formulario de registro y quiero que si un usuario introduce en el campo email un correo que ya existe en la base de datos salga un mensaje de que el correo ya existe. Lo estoy haciendo con un modelo vista controlador. He visto varias formas, pero no sé muy bien donde tengo que poner esa condición para hacer la comparación. Si me pudierais echar una mano. Muchas gracias. Adjunto códigos de las partes.

este es mi código de UsuarioController.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/DB/UsuarioDB.php');

class UsuarioController{
    
    public function crearUsuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad){
        $adaptadordb = new UsuarioDB();
        $usuarios = $adaptadordb->añadirUsuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad);
        
        return $usuarios;
    }
    
    }
```

Este es mi código de UsuarioDB.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Usuario.php');

class UsuarioDB{
    
    private $conexion;
    
    public function añadirUsuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad){
        $this->conectar();
        
        $salt = md5('Sunrise');
        $contrasena = $salt.$contrasena;
        $contrasena = md5($contrasena);
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, email, contrasena, telefono, ciudad) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stm = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        
        $stm->bind_param("sssssss", $un, $ua, $uf, $ue, $uc, $ut, $uci);
        $un = $nombre;
        $ua = $apellidos;
        $uf = $fecha_nacimiento;
        $ue = $email;
        $uc = $contrasena;
        $ut = $telefono;
        $uci = $ciudad;
        
        $stm->execute();
        
        
        return new Usuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad);
    }
    }
```

Formulario de registro

```html
<form action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
   <dl>
   <dt><label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="30" size="29"/></dd>
   <dt><label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" /></dd>
   <dt><label for="fecha_nacimiento">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" /></dd>
   <dt><label for="telefono">TELÉFONO</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" pattern="[0-9]{9}"/></dd>
   <dt><label for="ciudad">CIUDAD</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" /></dd>
   <dt><label for="email">EMAIL</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></dd>
   <p class="texto-contra">
   La contraseña debe contener al menos un número, una mayúscula, una minúscula y un mínimo de 8 caracteres.
   </p>
   <dt><label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label></dt>
   <button id="mostrar_contrasenaregistro" type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasenaregistro()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
   <dd><input type="text" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" /></dd>
   <dd><input type="submit" name="usub" value="¡Quiero registrarme!" /></dd>
   </dl>
</form>
```

Este es mi código que recibe los datos y hace el post

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');

$un = $_POST['nombre'];
$ua = $_POST['apellidos'];
$uf = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$ue = $_POST['email'];
$uc = $_POST['contrasena'];
$ut = $_POST['telefono'];
$uci = $_POST['ciudad'];


$cnt = new UsuarioController();
$ins = $cnt->crearUsuario($un, $ua, $uf, $ue, $uc, $ut, $uci);

?><html>

<head>
    <title>Registro completado</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Su registro se ha completado correctamente.<br> Se ha enviado un correo de confirmación a su cuenta.</h1>
        <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a>
    </div>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que te has creado un método llamado "crearUsuario", puedes crear otro método llamado por ejemplo "comprobarExistenciaMail" que haga el trabajo pertinente.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, creo que deberías colocar la condición dentro del método "crearUsuario":

```
public function crearUsuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad){
    $adaptadordb = new UsuarioDB();
    //invoca previamente el método que acabas de crear para comprobar si existe el mail
    //añade un condicional if/else que acabe el trabajo dependiendo de si el email existe o no.

    $usuarios = $adaptadordb->añadirUsuario($nombre, $apellidos, $fecha_nacimiento, $email, $contrasena, $telefono, $ciudad);

    return $usuarios;
}
```

Al margen de esto, te recomendaría dos cosas:

1. Intenta en la medida de lo posible no escribir código con "ñ". Por ejemplo he visto que has creado el método "añadirUsuario".

A pesar de que no tiene porque pasar nada (yo mismo tengo proyectos en los que he hecho eso y están funcionando correctamente), te podría dar problemas con la codificación.

2. En el fichero donde recibes los datos y haces el post, creo que el código PHP que pones, debería estar en el controlador. Es decir, eso es parte del código que procesa los datos y hace lo que tiene que hacer: eso es parte del controller.

Luego, una vez hayas procesado todos los datos, simplemente vuelca las variables que necesites en la vista (por ejemplo, el mensaje diciendo si el registro ha ido bien o no)

Desconozco si estás utilizando algún framework concreto o te has montado tu propio MVC.